# How can I read a file using FILE *fp and fopen?

Tags: c

So for this assignment I am supposed to read a file, and do things with the content. Right now I just want to be able to open the file, read it and print out how many lines it has. I believe I have the proper code to do so, but I have no idea how to "read" or connect to the file outside of my program! I am using the

```
FILE *fp = NULL; 
fp = fopen ();
```

part right? And that is how to open / connect to a file? But not sure what this does, and how it can connect to a file outside of the program. To read the file I have the user input their text file like

```
printf ("Enter the name of the data file: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]", &filename);
```

And then to read that I put

```
fp = fopen("&filename", "r");
```

but this doesn't seem right and it doesn't work. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, and how I can read a file that a user inputs? I am in an SSH matrix group if that makes sense, Like I log onto putty using an ssh terminal? Not sure how to explain it, but it's my schools online SSH thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fp = fopen("&filename", "r");
```

`filename`is variable , why are you passing it in `""` double quotes.

Try something like this below:

```
char filename[50]; // need a character array or buffer to hold the filename

printf ("Enter the name of the data file: ");
scanf ("%[^\n]", filename);   // no & operator
```

now use

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r");   // filename variable should contain complete path 

                              //with the actual file name
```

I think this should work.

Also you need to check the `fp` as

```
if(fp == NULL)   // It's always a safe way to proceed
   printf("Error in file opening\n");
```